# Transaction rollback when @Async method fails

Tags: java, spring, asynchronous

I am trying to read about Transaction but I cannot understand how would I rollback a async method call, is it even possible to do so.

I am facing an issue where User can select either select manual or driverless car for example. So if he selects driverless, then manual config will be disabled and other way round. Consider, he is moving from driverless to manual, driverless config is switched off and I make call to another service to switch off the manual configuration (which takes place in an Async call). I have added `@Async` for a reason as it is time consuming call.

example

```
// Caller
@Override
public void enableDriverlessDriving(DriverlessDriving driverlessConfig) {

     validator.validate(driverlessConfig);

     driverlessDao.update(driverlessConfig);

     if(drivelessConfig.isEnabled()) {

           manualService.onDrivelessEnabled(driverlessConfig.getUserId());
     }
}

// Callee
@Override
@Aysnc
public void onDrivelessEnabled(int userId) {

 .....
   // retrofit rest call. Timeout for 30 secs
   ManualConfig config = client.getManualConfiguration(userid,30);

   config.isEnabled(false);

   try {
         // retrofit rest call. timeout for 30 secs
         client.updateManualConfig(config, userId,30);
   }catch(CheckedExceptions e) { // throwing checked exceptions here.
      LOGGER.error(...)
      return;
   }

}
```

If there is an invoke error for rest call to disable manual config, the driverless config is switched on but manual config is not switched off, both are turned on.

Question:

1. Adding `@Transactional` to the caller and callee method work? - May be, but then it will affect the performance, there would be no use of `@Async` in this case.
2. Should caller method have `@Transactional`, but the `@Async` method should have `@Transactional(REQUIRES_NEW)`? Would having rollback on the caller method `@Transaction` rollback the transaction for checked exception in callee method?

I am expecting a solution where I achieve the integrity of data without compromising on performance (I want `@Async` to work in a way it works now)

Answer (score 2):

I will not suggest to merge `@Async` and `@Transactional` so i can run the service in either way. I just create async wrapper around the service and use this one instead if needed.

*@Transactional with @Async*

when a `@Transactional` Spring `@Component` calls a method annotated with `@Async` this does not happen. The call to the asynchronous method is being scheduled and executed at a later time by a task executor and is thus handled as a 'fresh' call, i.e. without a transactional context. If the `@Async` method (or the `@Component` in which it is declared) is not `@Transactional` by itself Spring will not manage any needed transactions.

If the `@Async` annotation is being used extra care should be taken with respect to transactions.In this case the transaction gets propagated through the call hierarchy from one Spring `@Component` to the other.

In order to make Spring manage the transaction of the `@Async` method either the `@Component` or the method itself should declare the `@Transactional` annotation, this way `Spring` will manage the transaction even if a method is being executed asynchronous.

Comment: If I understood your answer correctly, you are saying adding Transaction to the Async method would work? It would still not work because my caller function does not have Transaction (by default the propagation is REQUiRED). If I add Transaction to both the method then having Async won’t make sense as it will wait for Async thread to complete before committing the transaction. Can you give me an example? You can consider the same one I have above. What do you mean by create Async wrapper around the service?

Answer (score 1):

That's a great question, i came across at this some time ago.

1. No, adding `@Transactional` is not going to work because when the `@Async` method starts it is running on a new thread
2. I think there's no way to do a rollback based on a `@Async` method call.
3. You can get rollback to work without async calls, I don't know why you need to call the driverless method as `@Async`, but if you remove it will work.

Comment: Thanks. I need it Async because it is making a rest call to other service.

Answer (score 0):

Try below approach,

1. Create a separate class. Declare that as a bean under spring configuration.
2. Add all async methods in this class.
3. Autowire this class under the service class.
4. Inside a Transactional method from service class, call async method from the class created in 1st step.